# PyQt - Do not want modeless dialog always on top

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, modeless

I have a main window that creates modeless dialogs.  That's working well, but the dialogs are always in front of the main window.  Even if I go back to the main window and use it to give it focus, the dialogs always remain on top.  I cannot slide the main window on top of the dialogs.

I'm passing the main window's self as the parent to the dialog.

```
#In my main window
self.beacon_dlg = dialog_beacon.BeaconDialog(self)

#In the dialog class
class BeaconDialog(QDialog, ui_dialog_beacon.Ui_Dlg_beacon_soh):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BeaconDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Any idea how to allow the main window to be in front of the dialogs, and still close the dialog when the main window is closed (parent control)?

(I'm using PyQt 4.10 and Python 2.7 on Windows)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following and it seems to work, but not sure if it's the best method.  Instead of using:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(BeaconDialog, self).__init__(parent)
```

I used:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(BeaconDialog, self).__init__()
```

thus not making the dialog a child of the main window. (I still passed the main window as an argument to the class for other reasons)

However then in order to have the dialog shutdown correctly I had to overload the main window's closeEvent() and shut down the dialog myself with:

```
def closeEvnet(self):
    if (self.beacon_dlg) : self.beacon_dlg.reject()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [QDialog Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#details): "A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent's top-level widget (if it is not top-level itself). It will also share the parent's taskbar entry."

You could try to use [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not clear on the advantage or disadvantage of using QWidget in this case.  I'll post what I did come up with.

Comment: The advantage is that QWidget-based window is not always on top. QDialog is always on-top, and you don't want that.